# Recursively extract href links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have extracted the href links.But i want to write code that links will go to inner links or sublinks.
''' python

```
 from urllib.request import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 url = 'https://www.3gpp.org/'
 url_open = urlopen(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(url_open,'lxml')
 anchor = soup.findAll('a')
 for link in anchor:
     a = (link.get('href'))
     print(a)
```

The href links should extract inner links

Comment: So what's the error|problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to recurse into the pages being linked?

The simplest way to do that is to have a list/queue of URLs seeded with your root, loop until that is empty (removing one of the URLs and fetching the page), and every time you see a link add it to the queue for processing.

You will probably want to store visited URLs into a set (to avoid visiting the same page over and over), and whitelist / filter domains to avoid browsing the entire internet. You'll likely need urllib.parse in case the site you're browsing uses relative links.

A more divergent alternative is to use scrapy (basically a web scraping framework) instead of rolling your own.